# Canon EOS 70D, beginners camera?

Tags: canon, photography-basics

I am buying my first camera, but there is so much variety i don't know what to choose. Is Canon EOS 70D a good beginners camera, with the kit lens 18-135mm lens? Not looking in to buying another lens in the near future. I mostly take pictures of the nature, landscapes and street. Sometimes portrait. Is the kit lens OK for that, and is the camera good for its price or is there an equal good one that's cheaper?

Comment: It's a very sensible choice, both the camera and the lens, but if you can afford it get an 80D, a bit more expensive but it has new sensor, better AF system etc.

Comment: @rebecca I can see you're new here. Please don't be put off if your first two questions are closed as duplicates. We'd just prefer to refer you to good existing answers that have already been well-vetted than to repeat the same thing several times. But we really do try to be helpful! ;-)

Comment: Will you be lugging it around all day? It's a factor. A high-end point and shoot fits in your pocket, is always with you, and you'll learn just as much. Why do you want a DSLR? the 70D is a great cam and you'll enjoy it, but these days there are a lot of choices, from point and shoots to mirrorless.

Comment: I also started my hobby with the 70D and it was a good decision. I am photographing a lot these days and I am happy with most of the advanced features. But I have to nail: It is not just the camera you are buying. As a beginner, you have to learn the work with aperture, shutter speed and so on. If your budget is limit, better invest in a cheaper camera (or used 70D) and invest in some courses and workshops with pro-photographers. This is what really matters.

Comment: Depends what you are looking for.  If you have tiny hands, a smaller and lighter camera may be a good idea.  Have a look at the 100D.

Answer (score 1):

The 70D is the previous model in Canon's "prosumer" line. The current model is the 80D. The current prices on Amazon for a new 70D and 80D with 18-135mm lens are only about $150 apart ($1200 vs. $1350). If that difference isn't a big problem, I'd opt for the newer 80D -- the extra money is a good investment in a camera with somewhat better features and (more important) a longer supported lifetime. But if someone is offering you a really good deal on a new or gently used 70D, that camera won't be a bad choice at all. In short, the 70D is fine, and the 80D is somewhat better.

The kit lens will be fine for your needs. Kit lenses at this level are usually of good quality and meant to make the camera as useful as possible without requiring further immediate investment. If you really get into photography a day will come when you decide you want to expand your lens collection, but the 18-135mm will definitely get you started and serve your needs for a long while.

Comment: My personal experience is that once I bought my prime lens I *rarely* touch my kit lens(s), and it was just the Canon 40mm *f* /2.8 for ~ $130. If I could get a cheaper body and spend the money on a prime lens, it would *totally* be worth it.